# Ideal of non-units $R_I$, I is a prime ideal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm newbie in this topic.
Let $R$ be a (commutative) integral domain ($1\in R$) and $I$ a prime ideal of $R$. Then the set of all non-units forms an ideal $J$ of $R_I$ (the localization of $R$ at $I$). (Becker, Weispfenning, Gröbner Bases, exercises 1.120).
Here is what I try. 
(a) $\frac{0}{1}\in J$ is the zero element of $J$.
$\qquad \frac{0}{1} + j=j$ for every $j\in J$. 
(b) $x\in J$,$r\in R_I$ $\Longrightarrow rx\in J$. 
$\qquad$ If $x\in J$ then $x=\frac{a}{b}$ where $a\in R$, $b\in R-I$, and $r=\frac{c}{d}$ where $c\in R$, $d\in R-I$. Since $x$ is non-unit therefore $a$ is non-unit. 
How could I follow this calculation, what is the good idea?
(**Update 1**) (Following Dave's comment.) 
Since $a$ is non-unit thus $a\in I$. Now
$$
rx=\frac{ca}{db},
$$
where $ca\in I$, $db\in R-I$. (In the last step was used that $I$ is prime, and $R-I$ is multiplicatively closed.) So $rx$ is non-unit. 
(c) $x,y\in J$ then $x-y\in J$.
$\qquad$ Similarly, let $x=\frac{a}{b}$ where $a\in R$, $b\in R-I$, and
$y=\frac{c}{d}$ where $c\in R$, $d\in R-I$. Then $a,c\in I$. 
$$
x-y=\frac{ad-bc}{bd}.
$$
Here $ad-bc\in I$, $bd\in R-I$, so $x-y$ is a non-unit.

(**Update 2**) (See below the answer of rschwieb). 
If $x$ is a nonunit in any commutative ring $R$, and $r\in R$, then $xr$ is a nonunit. This doesn't use the fact that R is a domain or a localization or anything.

Comment: What exactly are the units of $R_I$? They're coming from the elements of $R$ that are not in $I$, because we can "divide" by these elements in $R_I$. So what does this tell us about $a$? Should $a$ be in $I$ or not in $I$?

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a nonunit in any commutative ring $R$, and $r\in R$, then $xr$ is a nonunit. This doesn't use the fact that $R$ is a domain or a localization or anything. Expressing it in terms of fractions just complicates it.  I would just start from there to finish b).

The 'hard part' is what you didn't mention, that the sum/difference of two elements of $J$ is in $J$.  Let's add this as c). You'll need to give a reason why $\frac{a}{s}+\frac{a'}{s'}$ is a nonunit if both the addends are nonunits, where $s,s'\notin I$.

It would help to know at the outset when any given fraction $\frac{a}{s}$ is a unit or not. (Hint: consider both $a\in I$ or $a\notin I$)